# How to change the Keyboard Symbols and Numbers?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, shift

I am using `Windows7 Pro` and my Keyboard looks like below

[image]

What I need is, I am pressing **`SHIFT + Symbl`** for Symbols like `!@#$%^&*`

Is there any way to change the keyboard setting by only pressing the key for symbols and `Shift + Num` for Numbers like 12345 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you could do this by making some modifications in Registry's key mapping, but since your case involves keys combinations (`Shift + number`), you can't do it that way.

So, give this a try:

1. Download [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It's a program that allows making key macros and more complex key remapping, amongst other cool stuff.
2. Then go to to the Desktop (or wherever you want), right-click, and then choose `New > AutoHotkey Script`.
3. Right-click the file you just created, and choose `Edit Script`. This will open the script file with the Notepad. Erase all its content and paste the following:

   ```
   #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
   ; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
   SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
   SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

   *1::!
   *2::"
   *3::§
   *4::$
   *5::send `%
   *6::&
   *7::/
   *8::(
   *9::)
   *0::=

   $+1::send 1
   $+2::send 2
   $+3::send 3
   $+4::send 4
   $+5::send 5
   $+6::send 6
   $+7::send 7
   $+8::send 8
   $+9::send 9
   $+0::send 0
   ```

> Note that the symbols on each keyboard may vary, so keep in mind that the structure is `originalkey::replacement`. For example, you have question mark (?) on your number 0, instead of the equal sign (=), you should write 
>   `*0::?` instead of `*0::=`

4. Save the script and open it (this time by left double-clicking it), and you're done! Every time you want to stop the script, just go to the notification icons, right-click the AutoHotkey icon, and choose "Exit".

Enjoy!

[Source](http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/24015-invert-number-row-on-main-keyboard/page-2)

[image: How to stop the script]